# Join operation on two databases from different servers in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, join, codeigniter-3

I have two mysql databases on two different servers.
I have loaded my database instances as db and db2.
Take a look at my code below :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    $this->db= $this->load->database('db', true); 
    $this->db2= $this->load->database('db2', true);  
    }

    function jointables()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('adb.items O');
        $this->db2->join('bdb.products P', 'O.ID=P.ID', 'inner');
        $this->db->limit(2,1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        print_r($query->result_array());

        echo "</br>";
         $this->db2->select('*');
        $this->db2->from('bdb.products');
        $this->db2->limit(2,1);
        $query2 = $this->db2->get();
        print_r($query2->result_array()); exit;

    }
}
```

In the jointables function I'm trying to apply an inner join on  items table from from db and products table from db2.
When the execution starts, according to me all the instances related to db gets executed in the first part till the line `$query = $this->db->get();`
The line `$this->db2->join('bdb.products P', 'O.ID=P.ID', 'inner');` doesnt get executed yet since the queries related to db2 are still to be executed.
Due to this I don't get the desired result. How do I make sure that the output of the db2 instance is available to me when the execution starts from the line `$this->db->select('*');` ?